# Proper Stack Exchange site to ask about: "Power calculation for Covid-19 UV sterilization For 1 meter distance"

Tags: support, site-recommendation

What is the proper Stack Exchange site to ask about [the following question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/496615/power-calculation-for-covid-19-uv-sterilization-for-1-meter-distance)?

> I like to know about the power needs to sterilization one 1x1 Meter
>   surface with 1 meter distance.
>
> I have seen [this](https://www.researchgate.net/post/How_much_UV-light_exposure_time_is_required_to_disinfect_a_laminar_flow_hood) post and one answer was:
>
> [image]
>
> > "Even at the minimum acceptable irradiance in a biosafety cabinet of
> >     40 W/cm2 (U.S. Department of Health and Human Services et al., 2000),
> >     it takes 12.5 minutes to reach 30,000 J/cm2 (1 W= 1 J/sec), which has
> >     been listed as germicidal for spore forming organisms by one UV
> >     manufacturer (www.uvp.com/pdf/ab-115.pdf)." "Even using the NIH/CDC
> >     criterion of the minimum acceptable irradiance in a biosafety cabinet
> >     of 40 W/cm2, it takes 12.5 minutes to reach the 30,000 J/cm2 found to
> >     inactivate spore forming organisms. Use of a UV light in excess of an
> >     hour or overnight is massive overkill." from:
> >     http://www.ehs.ucsb.edu/files/docs/bs/Meechan_and_Wilson_2006.pdf We
> >     typically leave the light on for 10 minutes prior to use, although
> >     after reading this, I'll up that to 15 minutes.
>
> Which the 30,000j/cm^2 is not correct and must be 30,000 micro J/cm2
>   like this:
>
> [image]
>
> so my calculation shows:
>
> 30×10⁻³÷(2×60)=0.00025 w/cm2
>
> which needs to calculate for one 4*pi*1 meter surface for 2 minuets
>   sterilization time, and because of distance effect on light based of
>   [this](https://www.researchgate.net/post/The_basic_way_to_calculate_UV_dose_from_a_UVC_15Watt_bulb) post it must be multiple by 4*pi*100^2 for 1 meter distance
>   to light source (lamp location), which means needs
>   0.00025×4×3.14×100×100=31.4 W as 2 minute sterilization.
>
> But I have seen this data from [this](https://spectrum.ieee.org/automaton/robotics/medical-robots/autonomous-robots-are-helping-kill-coronavirus-in-hospitals) robot:
>
> [image]
>
> > It takes between 10 and 15 minutes to disinfect a typical room, with
> >     the robot spending 1 or 2 minutes in five or six different positions
> >     around the room to maximize the number of surfaces that it disinfects.
> >     The robot’s UV array emits 20 joules per square meter per second (at 1
> >     meter distance) of 254-nanometer light, which will utterly wreck 99.99
> >     percent of germs in just a few minutes without the robot having to do
> >     anything more complicated than just sit there. The process is more
> >     consistent than a human cleaning since the robot follows the same path
> >     each time, and its autonomy means that human staff can be freed up to
> >     do more interesting tasks, like interacting with patients.
>
> and based on this data it use 20 joules per square meter per second
>   which it means use 2000 micro J /cm2:
>
> 20÷(100*100)=0.002
>
> which it gives the surface 2×60×20×10⁻⁴ = 0.24 J/cm2 energy, 0.24÷0.03 = 8
>   time more that 30,000 micro j/cm2!!!
>
> That needs 0.002×4×3.14×100×100 = 251.2 W for 1 meter distance and one
>   time sterilization and if 2 minutes for sterilization it needs, 50
>   times bigger than my calculation!!!
>
> Finally I don't know what UV lamp power is proper to sterilization
>   from 1 meter distance and (31.4 W or **250 W**)?
>
> What do you think about the not correct consideration in this
>   calculation? (I think it must related to different standard of UV
>   standard energy needs to sterilization!!)
>
> ***Update:***
>
> According to [this](https://sci-hub.tw/https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0190962220305089) paper:
>
> [image]
>
> and [this](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/full/10.1111/vox.12888):
>
> [image]
>
> I think it is proper to have **2j/cm^2** and **0.02 W/cm^2**.

The comments suggest to ask on the physics Stack Exchange site, but I ask here: Is this Stack Exchange site good for asking or do you suggest another Stack Exchange site. Also is there any bio-engineering Stack Exchange site to ask there?

Comment: I expect this question would be closed as off-topic on Physics.SE.

Comment: I am trying to find proper w.s/cm2 and j/cm2 from papers and commercial devises, so 40 mic w.s/ cm2 is come fron first paper which dont fit to the commercial robot with 8 times bigger j/cm2, by my calculations.

Comment: You can use superscript (`<sup></sup>`) as a higher fidelity version of "^" (short of [using MathJax](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020)).

Comment: @PM2Ring So what's the conclusion? No SE site for this problem? Or should the problem be broken down into subproblems more suitable for different SE sites?

Comment: @Ariser Sorry, I'm not familiar enough with all the sites on the network to give a good answer, I just know that it's likely to get closed on Physics, since engineering questions are  off-topic there, as are questions that ask to check calculations. It might be ok on Engineering.SE, I don't know. I suppose the OP has found the answer in another place (or has given up), since they appear to have abandoned this question.