# Suitable Stack Exchange site for open source community site recommendations for chat and find team work

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I would like to know what Stack Exchange site is the proper one to ask this question on:

[Proper community site for chat and find team work](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/9685/proper-community-site-for-chat-and-find-team-worker)

I have also seen on the Stack Exchange [tour](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/tour) page that it could be off topic because of:

> if you would like recommendations for Free & Open media

Comment: Are you and [this user](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/360265/soheil-paper) the same person? They asked [an identical Meta question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/347236/461068) about one of your questions just a few hours ago, and now you're asking one about one of theirs. If you are, I don't think you're breaking any rules, it just seems odd to me.

Comment: @F1Krazy yes, i ask a lot and in some SE site give negative point and restricted to ask so, using different account to ask there and doing this too much that don't have some of them in my phone or pc, so this situation happen, but SE site is smart and have some ip tracking system which detect same users, if the detect and want could close this kind of users.

Comment: Yeah, please don't create alternate accounts to get around question bans. At best, you'll receive a question ban on your other account as well; at worst, your other account will get deleted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I would like to know what Stack Exchange site is the proper one to ask this question on:

There isn't one. With very few exceptions, Stack Exchange sites don't answer questions asking for recommendations of other places or resources. Those that do have strict requirements for asking questions there (primarily that you must specify *in detail* what you're looking for), which your question doesn't meet.

Stack Exchange is not the place to ask this question.